# ::ng-deep isn't working for nested classes

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, styling

I am trying to overwrite the styling of a child component's color in the parent component. I tried doing multiple things but none of them are properly overwriting the child's original styling.

When I use ::ng-deep for just a single class it works

```
:host ::ng-deep class1 {
    color: black;
}
```

however when I use ::ng-deep for nested classes:

```
:host ::ng-deep class1 .class2 .class3 {
    color: black;
} 
// OR
:host ::ng-deep class1 {
    class2 {
        class3 {
           color: black;
        }
    }
}
```

it doesn't overwrite the child's original styling. I also tried using !important and it worked, but I am trying to avoid using that.

Comment: if `!important` fixes the issue, it means it has nothing to do with ng-deep. Can you show the selector your are trying to override ? To override a selector, you have to provide a more specific selector.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `:host` in front or use the `:host` in grandchild. If we want to style the host element of the component itself, we need the special :host pseudo-class selector. Would be best to use `::ng-deep` as a last resort and would recommend doing that in global `style.css` in your `/src`. Before using `:ng-deep` try to move your css to global style sheet and/or use `!important`. If you use `:ng-deep` in some child component, it would also affect everything else (that you may not see at first). Also pay attention where and when your adding dots. Your missing some from css classes.

To simply overwrite some stuff.

```css
.class1 .class2 .class3 {
    color: black !important;
}
```

This is not valid in normal css (yet), in scss you could nest selectors.

```css
.class1 {
    .class2 {
        .class3 {
           color: black !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Last resort.

```css
::ng-deep .class1 .class2 .class3 {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't think `::ng-deep` is still a thing, you should use `ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component instead, to disable CSS encapsulation :

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // <-- Add this here
})
```